# Add drop shadow to View in react native

Tags: react-native

How can I add drop shadow with below properties in react native that works in android:

```
Effect: Drop Shadow
Radius: 20dp
Offset: 0dp, -5dp
#1A000000
```

I tried this:

```
shadowColor: "#1A000000",
shadowOffset: {
  width: 0,
  height: -5,
},
shadowRadius: 20,
elevation: 20,
```

But it is not same as design.

Answer (score 0):

As outlined [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/shadow-props) in the React Native docs, the shadow style props are for iOS only, and elevation is the only shadow related prop for Android. I believe this is due to a limitation in the underlaying native APIs.

There are a bunch of 3rd party libraries that you can use, [`react-native-neomorph-shadows`](https://github.com/tokkozhin/react-native-neomorph-shadows) and [`react-native-simple-shadow-view`](https://github.com/ConduitMobileRND/react-native-simple-shadow-view) are 2 that i've used before.